# Need help on flexbox positioning

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

i kinda need help with the positioning of flexbox in a certain way, i know how to do the very basics, but i have no clue on how i can make them in a certain order and position

I already have the basics, but i want to have a flexbox where i have 6 buttons on each site of the screen, and another 6 below them, also on each site, like in the screenshot below (behold my mad graphic skills)

It  doesn't need to be my code, so i hope its not bad if i didn't post any, i just would like if someone could explain me how i would get this flexbox layout to work, or if someone even could give me an example, that be really great.
Thanks in advance!

[image: flexbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First did you used the [documentation of flexbox][1] ?

Then you need to use for everything

```
.style {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Then you nest all your buttons in several  themselves nested

For exemple for one button groupe :

```
<div class="style"> 
    <div class="style">
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class="style">
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you apply that on the rest
[1]: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, i already managed to get a little further already
I have the buttons on each site already using a placeholder.
Now i just need the Buttons after Mechanic to wrap down into the next line, i tried wrapping and setting the width of the placeholder, however, i cant seem to get it to work
https://i.imgur.com/KSPkYlE.png

Comment: The wrapping of flexbox allow your element to wrap automatically when the space granted is too small to contain all your inline elements. If you want to have 3 button on two lignes you need to use the code I put here.